# How can I see HTTP headers sent and received by Git?

Tags: git

How can I see the HTTP headers sent and received by `git`, when using the HTTP protocol for e.g. `git clone`?

Is the only way to use an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Try `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone`.

Comment: It doesn't show HTTP headers, but thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` in the environment to see the HTTP headers.  This, of course, works only with HTTP, not SSH.

Note that in newer versions of Git, this data is filtered so as to remove authentication headers and cookies, since you may not want to expose those things.  If you want to see them regardless, set `GIT_TRACE_REDACT=0`.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was looking for. FYI even without `GIT_TRACE_REDACT=0`, `git` still outputs something like `https://<user>:<pwd>@stash.example.net/scm/findash/chef-cookbook-qf-pm2.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack`... It's only `Authorization: Basic <redacted>` that becomes redacted.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), redact the path part of packfile URI that appears in the trace output.
So to see everything, including tokens, not just headers: `GIT_TRACE_REDACT=0`

See [commit 0ba558f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ba558ffb138f893f786d42b19689898ef456515), [commit 88e9b1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88e9b1e3fcbd3a8edcf1d54528c49f8237906aba) (10 Nov 2021) by [Ivan Frade (`ifradeo`)](https://github.com/ifradeo).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b5e7f5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5e7f5e5b18f1ec969c66a6e5b2b7f4caae34c0a), 10 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88e9b1e3fcbd3a8edcf1d54528c49f8237906aba): redact packfile urls in traces
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ivan Frade</sup>

> In some setups, packfile uris act as bearer token.
> It is not recommended to expose them plainly in logs, although in special circunstances (e.g. debug) it makes sense to write them.
>
> Redact the packfile URL paths by default, unless the `GIT_TRACE_REDACT` variable is set to false.
> This mimics the redacting of the Authorization header in HTTP.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/88e9b1e3fcbd3a8edcf1d54528c49f8237906aba/Documentation/git.txt#L835-L837):

> cookies, the "Authorization:" header, the "Proxy-Authorization:"
> header and packfile URIs. Set this variable to `0` to prevent this
> redaction.